# Как написать компонент, в котором DOM зависит от fetch-запроса?

Tags: reactjs

Есть некий родительский компонент, в котором находится состояние: валюта и текущий месяц. В дочернем компоненте находятся `handler`ы, которые изменяют состояние в родительском компоненте через пропсы. Каждый раз, когда пропсы изменяются, мне нужно сделать новый запрос к серверу и обновить `prices` в состоянии дочернего компонента, но у меня не получается это сделать, не попав при этом в infinite loop.

При монтировании дочернего компонента в **`componentDidMount`** я вызываю функцию `this.getPrices()`, которая загружает данные с сервера и обновляет состояние дочернего компонента через `this.setState()`. В этом нет проблемы. Но мне же нужно не один раз загрузить данные, а загружать их каждый раз при изменении пропсов. Поэтому я поместил вызов `this.getPrices()` в **`componentDidUpdate()`** и тут же попал в infinite loop.

На этапе написания этого вопроса возникла идея сравнивать предыдущие пропсы и новые и если в пропсах найдено какое-то различие, то в методе **`getDerivedStateFromProps`** вернуть `{ isLoadNeeded: true }` и затем уже в componentDidUpdate выполнять загрузку данных при наличии флага true в `isLoadNeeded`. Но в `getDerivedStateFromProps` нет доступа ни к `prevProps`, ни к `this.props`.

Родительский компонент:

```
const [minMonth, maxMonth] = [
    moment()
        .subtract(1, 'month')
        .endOf('month'),
    moment()
        .add(1, 'year')
        .startOf('month')
]

export const PriceHeatmap = () => {
    const [currency, setCurrency] = useState('rub')
    const [month, setMonth] = useState(moment().format('YYYY-MM'))
    const [oneway, setOneway] = useState(true)

    const onCurrencyChange = (x: string) => setCurrency(x)
    const onMonthChange = (x: string) => setMonth(x)
    const onOnewayChange = (x: boolean) => setOneway(x)

    return (
        <Heatmap
            currency={currency}
            month={month}
            oneway={oneway}
            onCurrencyChange={onCurrencyChange}
            onMonthChange={onMonthChange}
            onOnewayChange={onOnewayChange}
        />
    )
}
```

Дочерний:

```
class Heatmap extends Component<heatmapProps, heatmapState> {
    constructor(props: heatmapProps) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            prices: null
        }

        this.monthHandleChange = this.monthHandleChange.bind(this)
        this.onewayHandleChange = this.onewayHandleChange.bind(this)
        this.getPrices = this.getPrices.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('onCurrencyChange', e => {
            this.props.onCurrencyChange((e as CustomEvent).detail)
        })

        this.getPrices()
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        //this.getPrices()
    }

    monthHandleChange(action: 'increment' | 'decrement') {
        if (action === 'decrement') {
            let tempDate = moment(this.props.month).subtract(1, 'month')

            if (!tempDate.isBefore(minMonth)) {
                this.props.onMonthChange(tempDate)
            }
        } else if (action === 'increment') {
            let tempDate = moment(this.props.month).add(1, 'month')

            if (!tempDate.isAfter(maxMonth)) {
                this.props.onMonthChange(tempDate)
            }
        }
    }

    onewayHandleChange() {
        this.props.onOnewayChange(!this.props.oneway)
    }

    getPrices() {
        ky(
            `/api/prices/route?origin=${window.route_data.origin.code}&destination=${
                window.route_data.destination.code
            }&currency=${this.props.currency}&period=${this.props.month + '-01'}&oneway=${this.props.oneway}`
        )
            .json()
            .then(res => this.setState({ prices: (res as TP.Latest).data }))
    }

    render() {
        if (!!this.state.prices) {
            var pricesArr: { [key: string]: TP.LatestList } = {}

            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.prices.length; i++) {
                if (this.state.prices[i].depart_date in pricesArr === false) {
                    pricesArr[this.state.prices[i].depart_date] = this.state.prices[i]
                }
            }
            // получаем номер дня недели первого числа месяца
            var firstDayOfMonth = moment(this.props.month)
                .locale('ru')
                .startOf('month')
                .weekday()
            // заполняем пустые ячейки до первого дня месяца
            var blanks = []
            for (let i = 0; i < firstDayOfMonth; i++) {
                blanks.push(<td />)
            }
            // Находим количество дней в месяце и заполняем их
            var daysInMonth = moment(this.props.month).daysInMonth()
            var monthDays = []
            for (let d = 1; d <= daysInMonth; d++) {
                var dayKey = this.props.month + (d.toString().length === 1 ? '0' : '') + d
                var pricesHasDate = dayKey in pricesArr

                monthDays.push(
                    <td key={d} className="help">
                        <div className="day-number">{d}</div>
                        {pricesHasDate && (
                            <div className="price">
                                {Math.round(pricesArr[dayKey].value)}
                                <span className={'currency-' + this.props.currency}></span>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </td>
                )
            }

            var totalSlots = [...blanks, ...monthDays]
            var rows: Array<Array<JSX.Element>> = []
            var cells: Array<JSX.Element> = []

            totalSlots.forEach((row, i) => {
                if (i % 7 !== 0) {
                    cells.push(row) // if index not equal 7 that means not go to next week
                } else {
                    rows.push(cells) // when reach next week we contain all td in last week to rows
                    cells = [] // empty container
                    cells.push(row) // in current loop we still push current row to new container
                }

                if (i === totalSlots.length - 1) {
                    // when end loop we add remain date
                    rows.push(cells)
                }
            })

            var trs = rows.map((d, i) => {
                return <tr>{d}</tr>
            })
        }

        return (
            <div className="heatmap-holder">
                <div className="heatmap-head">
                    <div className="head-element">
                        <div className="head-description">Показывать цены в обе стороны</div>
                        <Toggle
                            id="heatmap-class-switch"
                            checked={false}
                            checkboxHandleChange={this.onewayHandleChange}
                        ></Toggle>
                    </div>
                    <div className="month-selector">
                        <div className="switch-left" onClick={() => this.monthHandleChange('decrement')}>
                            <i className="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div className="month-display">
                            {moment(this.props.month)
                                .locale('ru')
                                .format('MMMM YYYY')}
                        </div>
                        <div className="switch-right" onClick={() => this.monthHandleChange('increment')}>
                            <i className="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        </div>
                        <CurrencySelector />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="heatmap-body">
                    {!!trs && (
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>пн</th>
                                    <th>вт</th>
                                    <th>ср</th>
                                    <th>чт</th>
                                    <th>пт</th>
                                    <th>сб</th>
                                    <th>вс</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>{trs}</tbody>
                        </table>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Так это, добавьте в метод `componentDidUpdate` параметр `prevProps` и смотрите, изменились ли пропсы, в противном случае будет бесконечный цикл. В методе `componentDidUpdate` у Вас есть доступ и к `prevProps`, и к `this.props`

Comment: @DenisBubnov спасибо! Оформите как ответ и помечу вопрос как решённый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`componentDidUpdate`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) позволяет работать с DOM при обновлении компонента. Также он подходит для выполнения таких сетевых запросов, которые выполняются на основании результата сравнения текущих пропсов с предыдущими. Если пропсы не изменились, новый запрос может и не требоваться. Если не добавить проверку изменения пропсов, то может возникнуть бесконечный цикл. Для примера:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Популярный пример (не забудьте сравнить пропсы):
  if (this.props.month !== prevProps.month ||
      this.props.oneway !== prevProps.oneway ||
      this.props.currency !== prevProps.currency) {
    this.getPrices();
  }
}
```

P.S.: Небольшой совет. Метод `componentDidMount` подходит для настройки подписок - да, но не забудьте отписаться от них в `componentWillUnmount()`. То есть если Вы добавляете слушателя через [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) в [`componentDidMount`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), то по-хорошему нужно удалять этого слушателся через [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) в [`componentWillUnmount`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount).